# MOD_REWRITE (RewriteCond) supposed to ignore domain.tld/1 given DirectoryIndex is "1"

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
if it begins with 0 to 9 then ignore
if it begins with z then ignore.
```

That is what this mod-rewrite code says..

```
<Directory "/0/2/2">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([0-9])$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/z$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /z [L]
</Directory>
```

The directory index is "1"

```
DirectoryIndex 1
```

in the httpd.conf

which means when i go to

```
 domain.tld/
```

this should be same as

```
 domain.tld/1
```

and thus ignored by the mod-rewrite rule above.

but it is not ignoring it..

.. it ignores      domain.tld/1     just fine..

but won't ignore

```
 domain.tld/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if it begins with 0 to 9 then ignore
if it begins with z then ignore.
that is what this mod-rewrite code says..
```

Actually, it doesn't quite say that, because `$` is the end-of-string anchor. Here are some tweaks. The two conds are rolled into one, and the `/1` folder check is in the rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?[z0-9] [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(?!1)(.*) /z [L,NE]
```

This assumes that this lives in `httpd.conf`. If it lives in `.htaccess`, change the rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(?!1)(.*) z [L,NE]
```